# EF 5 Mixed Inheritance Types with Multi Layer Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, hierarchy

I am having an issue using entity framework to map an existing database to a code base. I can't seem to find any code that has done anything similar either. I need to have multi-layer inheritance and I need the layers to use two different mapping types. I am having some strange behaviour though. To reproduce the behaviour I have created a simple model and allowed EF to map it the way it wishes.

My entities are as follows:

```
public abstract class Root
{
    public int RootId { get; set; }

    public string RootProperty { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ChildA : Root
{
    public string ChildAProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ChildB : Root
{
    public string ChildBProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SubChildAa : ChildA
{
    public string SubChildAaProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SubChildAb : ChildA
{
    public string SubChildAbProperty { get; set; }
}
```

This results in the following schema:

[image: Schema]

My context is as follows:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SubChildAa> ChildAas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubChildAb> ChildAbs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChildB> ChildBs { get; set; }

    public MyContext()
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Root>().ToTable("Root");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildB>().ToTable("ChildB");

        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildA>().ToTable("ChildA");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildA>().Map<SubChildAa>(u => u.Requires("ChildAType").HasValue("SubChildAa"));
        modelBuilder.Entity<ChildA>().Map<SubChildAb>(u => u.Requires("ChildAType").HasValue("SubChildAb"));
        //base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }


}
```

I am trying to use TPT for the Root to Child (A or B) mapping and TPH for ChildA to SubChild. The main problem is that EF is putting the discriminator on the Root object. It is also putting the ChildA properties there, which I don't think is correct, but is less of a problem for now. With the discriminator being on the Root, it causes an error because ChildB does not map to the types in that discriminator.

Can someone suggest a way in which I can have the ChildA table actualLy maintain its own properties and discriminator without pushing them up to the root table.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
public abstract class Root
{
  [Key]
  public int RootId { get; set; }
  public string RootProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ChildA : Root
{
 [Required]
 int RootId 
 ForeignKey["RootId"]
 public Root Root {get;set;}    
 public string ChildAProperty { get; set; }
} 

public class ChildB : Root {
   [Required]
   int RootId   
   ForeignKey["RootId"]
   public Root Root {get;set;}      
   public string ChildBProperty { get; set; }
 }

public class SubChildAa : ChildA
{
  public string SubChildAaProperty { get; set; }
}

public class SubChildAb : ChildA
{
  public string SubChildAbProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In your context you want TPT for ChildA and ChildB

So

```
  public DbSet<ChildA> ChildAas { get; set; }

  public DbSet<ChildB> ChildBs { get; set; }
```

TPH for subchilds

```
  public DbSet<SubChild> Childs { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why would you inherit from Root as well as expose a Property of type Root in ChildA and B? I assume from DbSet<SubChild> you mean either of the two I defined and not a new type? I'm not really looking for a 'something like'. I understand how to map TPT and TPH independantly. The issue is with combining them.

Comment: I implemented the code and it does result in the schema I would like, with a few problems. There is no discriminator created, which is easy to solve by overloading OnModelCreating in the context and specifying a discriminator. The bigger issue is the ambiguity it creates with that domain model. I can create a ChildA and then a ChildB and set the Root of ChildA to be ChildB and it blows up (which is to be expected). This does solve the problem of having the ChildA properties and discriminator on the ChildA table, but it is a big design compromise as far as the code goes.

Comment: I inherited from the root because that is the design. However the Navigation properties also need to be associated with the foreign key and this bit is done in the ChildA and ChildB classes which is why the Root property gets repeated